# Handle files with content

Tags: ios, uti

I'd like to give users the chance to import data into my app. The app uses core data and my idea would be that the user prepares a text file and send it as email. In the "Open in..." dialog I like my app to be listed.

The file will be a text file but the content must follow certain rules, so that I'm able to extract the data I need to populate core data entities.

Must I define a custom UTI for that?? (I don't want my app listed for every text file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can define a UTI, as well as a MIME type for your format.  Give it a unique file extension and the fact that's it's encoded in plain text is not important (HTML, XML, etc. all fall into this category).

You don't specify how complex your text format will be, but if it's complex then you might want to consider using a language parser tool to process it, utilizing bison/flex (yacc/lex),  or ANTLR.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that the "Open in..." dialog doesn't show my app all the time. So I just need the right file extension bound to the UTI, right?

Comment: @BerndRabe Yeah I believe so.  Setting up a UTI isn't trivial but there should be enough examples around to get you through it.

Comment: Thanks. It's up and running ... somehow. The document is detected as the one my app can open but my in my   ´- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation´  all parameters are nil :( Thanks anyway.